# SQL Query To Show Total Each Time SalesMan Changes

Tags: sql-server-2008

This is my table structure with garbage data inserted.  What I am wanting to do is for each sales man (Frank and Joe) have a total row underneath them.  This is how I want the data to display when returned form my query

[image: Should Display]

This is table structure filled with garbage data, can someone assist me on how to set this up?

```
Create Table TurribleSetUp
(
  ID int,
  si varchar(200),
  salesmanname varchar(50),
  itemsold varchar(100)
)

Insert Into TurribleSetUp Values
(1, 'Home Frank Bad', 'Frank', 'stove'), 
(2, 'Internet Frank Left', 'Frank', 'table'),
(3, 'Store Frank Total Store Card', 'Frank', 'stereo')
,(4, 'Store Joe Bad', 'Joe', 'stove'), 
(5, 'Store Joe Right', 'Joe', 'stove'), 
(6, 'Joe, Person, High Five', 'Joe', 'car')
,(7, 'Frank, Person, High Five', 'Frank', 'car'),
(8, 'Left, Low Five, Joe', 'Joe', 'car')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
    select ts.salesmanname, si, count(itemsold) as Cnt, itemsold 
    from TurribleSetUp ts
    group by si, itemsold, ts.salesmanname
    union
    select salesmanname, 'Totals For '+ Salesmanname as si, count(itemsold) as Cnt, NULL as itemsold
    from TurribleSetUp 
    group by salesmanname
    order by ts.salesmanname
```

I ordered it by Salesman Name. I'm assuming you have some type of number that you'd order it by instead.

Comment: TY!  I was SO Confused on how to set this up, and couldn't ever get syntax accurate!!!

Answer (score 2):

Try;

```
select info, total_sale, itemsold piece_of_equipment_sold
from (
    select si info, count(itemsold) total_sale, itemsold, salesmanname 
    from TurribleSetUp 
    group by si, itemsold, salesmanname

    union all

    select 'Total for ' + salesmanname, count(itemsold), '' , salesmanname
    from TurribleSetUp 
    group by salesmanname
) x
order by salesmanname, total_sale
```

Comment: And when there will be 3 salesman 'Jimmy' you will add more and more `union all`?

Comment: @ lad2025 Thanks for your correction updated the answer.

Comment: Great, one more thing put it in order like in image and you are done :)